# Refreshing Sandbox

Tags: sandbox, sandbox-refresh

My company has production(enterprise edition) and developer sandbox. The developer sandbox is last refreshed in December. In the last 5 months many changes are made in production(eg: custom objects,buttons,etc). Now I would like to update sandbox to be an exact replica of Production. I know as ours is dev sandbox we can just have replica but not everything.

My question is if I go ahead and refresh the sandbox, will it it able to update the sandbox and have the exact replica of produciton?
Do I have to do any other to make sure that sandbox is exact replica of production.

Any insights would be helpful

Comment: If you refresh the sandbox it is not an update of your existing sandbox. It will delete your existing sandbox and create a new one. The new sandbox could be on a different CS instance to your current one.

Comment: Note: unless you are paying extra for a full data sandbox, your sandbox will contain an exact copy of all you production design elements, but NOT the data.

Comment: I know that once I click refresh it will delete everything in the present sandbox and copy metadata from production. My doubt is will this be enough for me to go ahead and start coding etc in sandbox. I guess you understood my doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you refresh your Developer sandbox from production, you will have all metadata in it. But data will not be available. You will have everything ready to continue development in Developer sandbox.